# Deploy a bundlet and get the dependent bundles from spring EBR

Tags: grails, osgi, eclipse-virgo, spring-dm

I have a WAR file that was built using grails framework and OSGi plugin. When I try to deploy it in Eclipse Virgo it fails because the related dependencies are not yet deployed.
Is there a way to tell Virgo to fetch the dependency bundles from [spring EBR](http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/) repository for example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure Virgo to use a remote repository to provide the missing dependencies automatically. However, there is an issue in using the SpringSource EBR as a remote repository because Spring framework, which is deployed during Virgo startup, has a very large number of optional/transitive dependencies. When these are pulled in from the EBR they include normally exclusive alternatives and the net effect is that Virgo startup fails.

So the recommendation is either to put the dependencies you want locally in repository/usr or, if you need a remote repository, to set up your own Virgo instance to act as a repository server and put the dependencies in the repository hosted by the repository server.

Comment: Thank you. Actually I was installing bundles one by one and the server encountered a conflict. Then it won't restart. To diable all the installed dependencies should I empty the /usr directory ?

Should I follow it bundle by bundle until it works or there is a better solution ?